# 404 Error on azure website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have setup a AppService based website in Azure (using Node.js) in the "F1 Free" Tier. Very often when we browse to a JSON file in the site, we get a 404 not found error. But, when we hit refresh in the browser, it loads.

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Is this a symptom of a larger issue we should be aware of?

Comment: Is that a static file or something you serve through an Express/Koa route? Is the 404 showing up in your application log as well?

Comment: It's a static file that another server polls periodically. So, I suppose it is expected from the free tier?

Answer (score 2):

Not much to go on, in your question, but... from a "happens very often" perspective:

[App Service Free tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview) is going to have frequent app pool recycling after inactivity. So, after (I believe) 20 minutes, your app is being recycled, and your first hit will likely be delayed (or hit a timeout).

You'd have to use a paid tier to enable "[always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#application-settings)."

Answer (score 0):

Free tier has enforced limits on traffic and compute resources, but i'm finding it difficult to call it unreliable.

If the static path is not going through the Node stack (i.e. you have a `/static` rule in `web.config`), then you should probably enable IIS tracing to check what's going on.

There's a *Failed Request Tracing* button in the Application Settings in the Portal, use that to [capture detailed context for the 404](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/). You can use [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) to read the traces (*Debug Console* has a file browser and traces get written to `d:\home\LogFiles\W3SVC*`).

If all else fails, upgrade to at least **Basic** and see if you're still in trouble. If so, definitely open a support case from the Azure Portal.